# Weakly amenable Banach algebras

Tags: banach-algebras

In Dales' monograph ''Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity'' there is Proposition 2.8.64 which says that Banach algebra homomorphisms with dense range preserve contractibility as well as amenability. They also preserve weak amenability but under an additional assumption that the algebra be commutative. Is this assumption necessary?